# NetSuite UserEvent Execution log not working while Purchase Order Created from SOAP Request

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a User UserEvent script for purchase order. When Purchase Order created from NetSuite UI its working fine, while Purchase Order created from SOAP xml request, this script not able to capture any log on suite script Execution log ?

I have checked all the below parameter for executing script .

1- Setup > Integration > SOAP web service prefrences >  RUN SERVER SUITESCRIPT AND TRIGGER WORKFLOWS (checked true)

2- APPLIES TO -> PurchaseOrder

3- Log Level -> Debug

4- Status -> Testing/Release (checked in Both case)

5- Deployed -> checked

6- Inactive -> false

7- Roles -> All Roles/ Specific Roles (Checked with both )

While UserEvent Script for Items working fine on UI & SOAP Request case.

TIA

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope Public
 */
define(["N/log"], function (log) {
        var exports = {};
        /**
         * Function definition to be triggered before record is loaded.
         *
         * @param {Object} scriptContext
         * @param {Record} scriptContext.newRecord - New record
         * @param {Record} scriptContext.oldRecord - Old record
         * @param {string} scriptContext.type - Trigger type
         * @Since 2015.2
         */
        function beforeSubmit(scriptContext) {
          log.debug({ "title": "Before Submit", "details":"Before Submit Event"});
        }

        function afterSubmit(scriptContext){
          log.debug({ "title": "After Submit", "details": "After Submit Event"});
        }
        exports.beforeSubmit = beforeSubmit;
        exports.afterSubmit = afterSubmit;
        return exports;
    });
```

Comment: The script deployment has execution contexts listed on the context filtering tab. Check if SOAP Web Services is in the list.

Comment: The most common reason for a user event not triggering is the deployment status is Testing and the audience doesn't include the user it is being tested under.

Comment: As i checked SOAP Web Services is in the list